# Lack of warnings on loop counter

Tags: c++

I'm having difficulty understanding why the following code doesn't warn:

```
unsigned test = 0xffffffff;

for (unsigned char i = 0; i < test; i++)
{
    // Some code
}
```

This is on Visual Studio 2010, but GCC apparently doesn't warn either.  Anyone know why?

Comment: Show your build flags, what warnings are you requesting?

Comment: Because not warning is default behavior, so a case needs to be made *for* warning?

Comment: fwiw, there _is_ a warning if you mark `test` as `const`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a language point of view, there is nothing to warn about.  `i` is promoted to `unsigned int` before the `<` is evaluated.  And it's perfectly well-defined to increment an `unsigned char` such that it wraps around to zero.

<s>The fact that this code does something irritating is unfortunate.  But it's not clear what rule a compiler would need to apply in order to detect this sort of thing.</s>

**Thanks to @unwind in the comments below:** you can get GCC to warn about the fact that this comparison must always evaluate to true using the [`-Wtype-limits`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wtype_002dlimits-411) flag.

**Update 2:** Apparently the above option doesn't work in this case (I don't have a "modern" version of GCC to hand right now...)

Comment: GCC has a warning ([`-Wtype-limits`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wtype_002dlimits-411)) which warns for always-true comparisons, I guess that would apply here.

Comment: @unwind: That's a good point; the real problem is that comparison must always evaluate to true.

Comment: (Nor clang) I guess it's because this is purely a logical error. There are no syntax errors, everything's well defined, and there's no ambiguity. It seems the option is for cases where it's clearly impossible, such as `if (x < 0)` where x is unsigned.

Comment: +1 For the only answer realizing that `i` can never overflow.

Answer (score 1):

`i` is promoted to `unsigned` and then compared to `test`. No problems here. Well. i++ will overflow the char, but that is a run-time problem. What I mean is that after 255 it will be 0, and that maybe not what the author espect, making the cycle potencialy infinite if there are not other form of terminating it ( a break, a retun, etc) That is a posible "logical" run time error.

Comment: *"i++ will overflow the char, but that is a run-time problem."* - `i` does *never* overflow, so there is no run-time problem.

Comment: @Christian Rau Of course, what I mean is that after 255 it will be 0, and that maybe not what the author espect, making the cycle potencialy infinite if there are not other for of terminating it ( a break, a retun, etc) That is a posible "logical" run time error.

Answer (score 1):

Because comparing an `unsigned char` and `unsigned` is perfectly legal. The problem only starts to show up due to the loop counter obviously overflowing, but I'm not sure compilers will ever be [*that* smart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telepathy).

Comment: *"The problem only starts to show up due to the loop counter obviously overflowing, but I'm not sure compilers are that smart."* - The compiler needn't be that smart either, because this isn't even a problem, since unsigned types can never overflow.

Comment: Well, the loop counter just wraps around after 255, effectively creating an infinite loop. That's what I meant... I think the proper word is *carry*.

Comment: Yes, but this is not an actual problem to be diagnosed, as only the programmer can even define if this is supposed to happen or not. It's not that the compiler is too dumb or bad at anaylyzing to find this *"problem"*. He just isn't supposed to even consider this.

Comment: But that's what I wanted to express with *that* smart. It's a *do-what-I-mean* question.

Comment: But your answer, especially the last sentence, sounds like this *could* be possible for a sufficiently good hypothetical compiler. But it wouldn't just require *"really smart analysis, ensuring that the loop-counter doesn't get modified somewhere in the loop body"*, but actual mind reading.

Answer (score 1):

From the draft standard:

> **4.5 Integral promotions**
>
> A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t whose integer
> conversion rank (4.13) is less than the rank of int can be converted
> to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all the values of the
> source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a
> prvalue of type unsigned int.